# set interval inside a function must return resolve message or reject

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a timer, and trying to exit from the callback hell that is happening inside the code I am writing, this is a part from the code I have written, the problem is that I am not receiving the feedback from the promise, so no resolve message, no reject message.
what is the problem?

```js
       var timer = 15;

        var startTimer = (timer) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
               if(resolve){
                var countDown = setInterval(() => {
                    console.log(timer);
                    timer--;
                    if (timer == 0) {
                    clearInterval(countDown);
                    return "YOU ARE LOSER";
                    }
                }, 1000);
               }
               if(reject){
                   return "sorry something went wrong!";
               }
            })
        }

        startTimer(timer)
        .then(message =>{
            console.log(message);
            //the message should be "You are loser!".
        })
        .catch(message =>{
            console.log(message);
        })
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the concept of resolve and reject in a Promise. 
I suggest you try and read this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Why are you checking if resolve exists? It's a function which will _always_ exist.

Comment: I want to execute the rest of the code only when the timer is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using promises wrong, take a look at this [friendly tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-write-a-javascript-promise-4ed8d44292b8/).

You resolve or reject the value that you want to return.

```js
var timer = 15;

var startTimer = (timer) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      var countDown = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(timer);
        timer--;
        if (timer == 0) {
          clearInterval(countDown);
          resolve("YOU ARE LOSER");
        }
      }, 1000);
    } catch (err) {
      reject("sorry something went wrong!");
    }
  })
}

startTimer(timer)
  .then(message => {
    console.log(message);
  })
  .catch(message => {
    console.log(message);
  })
```

Simplified version without promises

```js
var timer = 10;
var countDown = 0;

var startTimer = fn => setInterval(() => {
  console.log(timer);
  if (--timer === 0)
  {
    clearInterval(countDown);
    console.log("You lose");
    if(fn)
    fn();
  }
}, 500);

function onTimerFinished() {
console.log("Timer has finished");
}

try {
  countDown = startTimer(onTimerFinished);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: do you think that I am implementing this job in the best way?

Comment: what is better than what I am doing here? I'm looking for someway to get out of the callback hell. because that I am returning a promise, is what I am doing Good?

Comment: To be honest, in this scenario you don't need any promises. You can achieve the same outcome without using any promises.

Comment: How I can do that? inside if (timer == 0) { here I will write all of the rest code?}

Comment: @jonas The 'callback hell' you refer to has been addressed with the use of `async` / `await`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show it's basically the same without promises. You may need promises as you add more to your code.

Comment: so it's not possible to exit from the callback hell using es6 then and catch methods?

Comment: the problem in your updated answer is that in this way I'll not be able to execute the rest of the code after the timer finishes look here:
try {
countDown = startTimer(); 
console.log("this text should happen only after the timer finishes, but it's not doing that.");
}

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realise you needed to do that. If you really don't like the promise pattern, you could pass a function callback which you then call when you clearInterval

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

`resolve` and `reject` are functions to call. `resolve` is for when the asynchronous operation has completed, and `reject` for when an error has occurred. When invoking these functions, you can supply a value to propagate along the promise chain.

```js
var count = 5

var startTimer = (count)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        try {
            var intervalId = setInterval(()=>{                    
                if(count) { 
                    console.log(count--)
                    return
                } 
                clearInterval(intervalId)
                resolve( "YOU ARE LOSER")
            }, 1000)
        } catch {
            reject('sorry something went wrong!')
        }
    })
}

startTimer(count)
    .then((result)=>{ console.log(result) })
    .catch((err)=>{ console.log(err) })
```

Comment: do you think that this is the best way for achieving this goal? I mean to exit from the callback hell.

Comment: Promises and async/await help you avoid callback hell. There is nothing wrong with this example in my opinion.